# Read references from a .bib file in IEEEtran

Tags: citing, ieeetran

I am new to Latex. I am trying to put the **references as well as cite them**. I am doing the following:

**1.** Created a `refer.bib` file with following content

```
@String{j = {Journal}}
@String{jof = {Journal of}}
@String{procof = {Proceedings of}}

@misc{erec04,
  author = {European Renewable Energy Council},
  title = {{Renewable Energy Scenario to 2040}},
  howpublished = "\url{http://www.erec.org/fileadmin/erec_docs/Documents/Publications/2040Exec_Sum.pdf}",
  year = {2004},
  note = "[Online; accessed 07-Mar-2013]"
}
```

**2.** Then i used the following lines in my `main.tex`

```
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliography{refer}
```

**3.** Then i tried to cite as following:

```
During smooth pursuit\cite{erec04}
```

But in the pdf version i just saw the following

```
During smooth pursuit[?]
```

Please suggest me how to do it properly?

Comment: @Johannes_B: i have read the answers there. But unfortunately the answer which is accepted there, i couldn't understand it and don't know how to solve my problem

Comment: What part could you not understand? Giving us more explicit information about what it is that you're doing would help us in figuring out how to help you. Are you running `pdflatex` `bibtex` `pdflatex` then `pdflatex` again?

Comment: @Adam: Sorry, as i am new..i don't know what things have you mentioned...i am using `Texmaker` and trying to read the references from `refer.bib` file. After compilation, a `pdf view` window opens

Comment: Try hitting `F6` to start pdflatex, and `F11` to start bibtex.

Comment: Compiling a bibliography is very basic stuff. Please read some [introductory material](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/).

Comment: You need to compile a document four times when you have references: first with `pdflatex`, then with `bibtex`, then with `pdflatex`, and then with `pdflatex` again. @Johannes_B pointed out the key bindings in TeXMaker, so you should hit `F6` `F11` `F6` and then `F6` again. That should work.